# Mysql performance without "Database" specified in connection string

Tags: mysql

In my Web Application I used to connect to my MySql database with a connection string such as

```
"Server=mysql.myserver.com; Port=3306; Database=my_database; Uid=user; Pwd=password;[...]"
```

Now, in some parts of my application i need to query multiple databases.

My first tought was to create multiple connections, one for each used database (up to 12 in my case).

Then i tought that i could use a single connection, without setting the "Database" parameter, such as

```
"Server=mysql.myserver.com; Port=3306; Uid=user; Pwd=password;[...]"
```

and then specify the target database in each individual query. eg.

```
"SELECT * FROM my_database.my_table"
```

I guess that the single-connection solution can be a better decision since i won't increase the number of active connections, which can be especially usefull in my case since it is a Web Application, possibly with a consistent amount of simultaneous users.

However, i'm not entirely sure about what's the best option. Some questions comes to my mind: Do i lose performance on execution plan generation? Worst caching? Anything else i'm totally missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You only need 1 connection. Specify the target database in your queries.

Comment: At least if the user account allows access to all databases. If you need different users for each database, then you need different connections.

Comment: Yes, the database user has access to all the databases. I guess I'll go for the single connection solution then, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use a single connection.

The only drawback is that you will either need to hardcode the schema (database) name, or make it configurable which is a little inconvenient.

Multiple connections however have serious drawbacks:

1. No join's across schemas
2. Transactions become a lot more complicated
3. More complicated to implement and use
4. Some wasted time spent connecting all of them (it adds up)
5. The server will have a lot more idle connections

Comment: Thanks! Most of the queries are built dynamically and the context of my application already knows which database is to query, so this should not be a hard task to implement. I'm happy to hear that nobody is pointing at any flaw of a connection without the "Database" parameter set, I'll definitely just go for it.

Comment: I guess it should also be noted, that the connection having a "current database" doesn't really matter. It's only used if the query doesn't specify it.

Comment: Oh, ok. So the database that i set in the connection string is not binding me to only use that database, I can still query other databases if I put the database name in the queries. If I understood that correctly.
This helps me believe that there are no real underlying differences in how mysql handles a connection without that parameter.
Really nice to know, thanks again!

Comment: Yes, there are no underlying differences. The current database can also be changed at any point with `USE <db_name>`.